# Связать два проекта C#

Tags: c#, winforms, linq2sql

У меня в программе два проекта WinForms, как можно связать эти проекты? И при работе с данными  если буду связывать БД со вторым проектом с помощью LINQ To SQL, как сделал в первом проекте, будет какой-то конфликт?

Comment: а можно подробнее? это на выходе два .exe или (.exe и .dll)?

Comment: Что вы подразумеваете под "связать"? Есть несколько способов взаимодействия между процессами.

Comment: @Владимир Мартьянов  Мне нужно что при щелчке в `menuStrip` открывалась форма из второго проекта,что бы я там мог работать с БД уже связанный в первом проекте.

Comment: @Dmitry   (.exe и .dll)

Comment: @VardanVardanyan, а почему не использовать одно приложение?

Comment: @VardanVardanyan, а ну так это меняет дело, бросте референсы на dll

Comment: DLL работает в том же процессе, что и EXE. Так что тут не межпроцессное взаимодействие. Что у вас где - не ясно.

Comment: @Dmitry  просто много форм,решил добавить что бы не смешались и проще было найти

Comment: @VardanVardanyan в запускаемый проект добавте референс на проект с библиотекой

Comment: @Dmitry спасибо,а как можно работать с БД во втором проекте???,БД уже связан с первой

Comment: @VardanVardanyan, это уже более сложная схема работы, нужно заводить отдельную библиотеку с моделями, отдельно с DAL, это если крупно разделять, можно разделить еще мельче, но тогда и проектов будет десяток :) короче, для бд однозначно нужно делать DAL :)

Comment: @Dmitry как понимаю нужно использовать `MVC` для этого?

Comment: @VardanVardanyan, модели используются не только в MVC. Модель, это описание сущьности

Comment: @Dmitry какой лучше использовать,или где можно почитать об этом?

Comment: @VardanVardanyan, почитайте про проектирование приложенеий с трехзвенной архитектурой

Comment: @Dmitry если БД буду связать со вторым проектом с помощью  `Linq To Sql` как сделал в первом проекте какой то конфликт будет?

Comment: @VardanVardanyan пожалуйста, не используйте выделение кодом на том, что кодом не является - http://meta.ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1328/%D0%9A%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%B4%D0%B0-%D1%81%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%B8%D1%82-%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%B7%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%B2%D0%BD%D1%83%D1%82%D1%80%D0%B8%D1%81%D1%82%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%87%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B5-%D0%B2%D1%8B%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D0%B4%D0%BB%D1%8F-%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%B0

Comment: @PashaPash понятно буду внимательным